# why table row does not close?

Tags: tables

I am wondering why the row that ends {equations of motion} does not close like the one above it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline

            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{{\bf Name and theme of lesson:} Equations of motion}\\\hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{\bf Subject area:} Linear motion & {\bf Class }RTU & {\bf No.}1\\ 
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Lesson objectives} Derive equations of motion\\\hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf Material and resources:}Whiteboard, Marker\\...

      \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, be aware that `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```tex
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{{\bf bold text} normal text} \\
```

instead of

```
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\bf bold text} normal text \\
```

That is, the "normal text" should also be part of the 3rd argument of `\multicolumn`.

Full example, with `{\bf ...}` replaced with `\textbf{...}`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}
    {\textbf{Name and theme of lesson:} Equations of motion}
    \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}
    {\textbf{Subject area:} Linear motion} 
    & \textbf{Class} RTU 
    & \textbf{No.}1
    \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}
    {\textbf{Lesson objectives} Derive equations of motion}
    \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}
    {\textbf{Material and resources:} Whiteboard, Marker} 
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As  far as I see, thble has three columns, why you define four?

Comment: @Zarko hmm I didn't even notice that :)

Answer (score 0):

With `tabullaray` package, for exercise:

```
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={lcc}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \textbf{Name and theme of lesson:} Equations of motion 
                                        &   &                           \\
\textbf{Subject area:} Linear motion    &   \textbf{Class} RTU
                                            & \textbf{No.} 1            \\
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \textbf{Lesson objectives:} Derive equations of motion
                                        &   &                           \\
\SetCell[c=3]{l} \textbf{Material and resources:} Whiteboard, Marker
                                        &   &                           \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

- as you can see, all lines in table are defined in table preamble
- your table use only three rows, therefore in above MWE are defined three columns instead of four in your MWE
- `\SetCell[c=3]{l} ...` is equivalent to `multicolumn{3}{l}{ ... }` in classic tables, however it consider vertical lines defined in table preamble

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: say if I wished to crete something and then span 3 columns how can I try this?  \hline
\textbf{Pre-lesson check} & \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}\\
\hline

Comment: By the way I should have had I 4 columns.

Comment: I understand \bf is deprecated in favour of \textbf..

Comment: @ShaneG, from your question doesn't follow, that shoed table has only three columns. If this is not a case, please make your question more clear. Other comment I not understand. It may be helpful to read some introductory text about table settings, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

Comment: There are  4 columns in my original post. I'm not sure why it changed to three! Anyway there should be four.

Comment: @ShaneG, you define four columns, but use only three.